# Should I check the type of input to my class properties?

Tags: python, class, properties, duck-typing, code-structure

I am a fairly new developer in Python and was getting accustomed to the idea of "Duck Typing".

I have a class I used in another module to do particular things with it, for example, access it's name and version. This module obviously cannot handle arbitrary values and needs the name to be a string and version to be an integer.

Currently, I am enforcing the type of input to my class properties using isinstance():

```py
class ExampleObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None
        self._version = None

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        if not isinstance(name, str) and name is not None:
            raise ValueError("Expected string, got {0}".format(type(name)))
        
        self._name = name

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self._name

    @version.setter
    def version(self, version_number):
        if not isinstance(version_number, int) and version_number is not None:
            raise ValueError("Expected int, got {0}".format(type(version_number)))

        self._version = version_number
```

If I go with the idea of Duck typing, I should not be enforcing a particular type to my properties. If I drop my type checking and some other developer starts using these properties for other data types, it can lead to the module I wrote breaking. Basically, the module expecting an integer and it gets something else. What's the correct approach to this?

I checked several related questions regarding this but none of them covers what would happen if we skip the type checking and how to enforce that other developers don't break things because they were not aware of another module using these properties to perform type specific things.

Comment: "Please note I can only use python 2 to try anything." - Python 2 is end of life since Jan 1st 2020.  If you are trying to maintain / develop an application that is Python 2 (only) you are just digging yourself deeper into your hole.  And if you can't install Python 3 side-by-side with Python 2 to try things out, there is something wrong with your platform!

Comment: Hey @StephenC, I myself would like to switch to python 3 but I am not sure if my code will be compatible with other pieces of software. For context, I am working on a class which is generic enough to be used in several places or software with their own python version. 

The place where I need it runs python 3.7 by default which is not a problem but there are other software which can use this class running on python 2. These are third party software and I am not in control over their native python versions.

Comment: *"I myself would like to switch to python 3 but I am not sure if my code will be compatible with other pieces of software."*  - The best (in fact only) way to find out is to try it.  *"... but there are other software which can use this class running on python 2."* - The practical solution in the long run is to make it *their problem*.  State that your code requires Python 3.7 or later.  If "they" then want to run it on an end-of-life version of Python, that is their problem, not yours.  (Unless "they" are *paying you* good money to do the extra work to support *their* legacy requirements.)

Comment: @StephenC, very well, thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't even thinking on these terms and now that I focusing some thought on this, I wrote quite a few things in Python 2 without thinking over whether it is really necessary or not in the name of compatibility. I will switch to Python 3 and just see what happens. I will remove the Python 2 comment in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's duck typing puts the onus on you to enforce it. If the parameter will be passed by the user, it can be a good idea to perform casting and/or type validation. For example, you can try casting `version_number` to an int using the built-in `int()` method. If this fails (ie. `version_number` cannot be converted to a string), the `int()` method raises a ValueError for you, which you can check for as follows:

```py
@version.setter
def version(self, version_number):
    try:
        version_number = int(version_number)
    except ValueError: #when casting to int fails, Python raises a ValueError
        # handle error here
    #otherwise, version_number is now a valid int, so continue
```

If you're the only one that will be using your code, you can forgo this validation at your own risk. Regardless of which you choose, it's also a good idea to use type hints. Type hints don't do anything at runtime (so they won't perform any casting/validation for you), but can help assist your IDE in reminding you what type is expected for a parameter or return. Type hints for your function might look as follows:

```py
@version.setter
def version(self, version_number: int) -> None:
```

No type hint is required on the `self` parameter, as your IDE can tell `self` will be an `ExampleObject`. The type hint `int` on the parameter `version_number` indicates that this parameter should be an int. Finally, the return type hint of `None` indicates this function doesn't return anything.

Source: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html

Comment: Hey, apologies but I forgot to mention that I can only use python 2 for my code so type hints are not an option. Also, isn't casting doing the same thing of enforcing type in a round-a-bout way? One way or another, I am still enforcing it so why not use the less expensive isinstance()?

Comment: I have decided to drop python 2 and use python 3 but my question over the casting is still there. So let me know what you think about it.

Comment: @Parikshit It depends on how you want to handle the error. If you want to raise a ValueError with a custom message (to either show in the console or handle while calling the method), your original method works. If you'd rather handle it gracefully inside the method, you can use the try/catch paradigm to avoid an uncaught exception.